# How to get rid of a second CrashPlan icon in the menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar

Everytime I restart, I get two crashplan icons in the menu bar.

If I close one of them, the other still remains.

How can I get rid of one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me when I installed CrashPlan Mac menubar app over a year ago, and when a recent version of CrashPlan included its own menubar. If that's the case for you, see if you can find the CrashPlan Menubar app (in your Applications folder?) and just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Try holding <kbd>Command</kbd> while dragging the icon off of your menu bar. This typically works for me on most unwanted menu bar icons.

[How to Use the Secrets in the OS X Menu Bar](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_secrets_os_x_menu_bar)